# OCFS2: "Bad magic number in inode" every time mounting specific volume; fsck fixes it?

Tags: linux, ocfs2

I have 5 OCFS2 volumes on an iSCSI SAN that a handful (5) of servers mount.  There is one volume in particular that *never* mounts cleanly after reboot.  The error you get when trying to mount is

```
hamguy:/dev/disk/by-label # /etc/init.d/ocfs2 start
Starting Oracle Cluster File System (OCFS2) mount.ocfs2: Bad magic number in inode while
trying to determine heartbeat information
```

The only way I've found to fix it is by

```
fsck.ocfs2 /dev/sde1
```

fsck reports an error trying to lock the cluster down, and then exits.  The volume is now able to be mounted.

OCFS2 information

```
kendal@hamguy:~> rpm -qa |grep ocfs2
ocfs2console-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
ocfs2-tools-o2cb-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
ocfs2-tools-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
```

Operating system is OpenSuSE 11.2 x86.

Has anyone some insight into this?

Thanks,

Kendall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dump2fs /dev/sde1 | grep 'superblock'
fsck.ocfs2 -b ALTERNATE_SB # is one of the backup superblocks.
```

i would have a backup before ...

Comment: Thanks.

Any idea what the root cause is?

Comment: maybe had a dirty umount ... as in crashed server - if is what you need it please accept the answer - thanks

Comment: I guess the crash server is possible...AFAIK, this has been going on for a few years, and as been around since the volumes were created.